# Understanding perl use structures

Tags: perl

I am trying to understand some messy Perl where there a lot of modules that use each.  We end up having everything very intertwined and in some cases, global variables are used without using what defines them (for example, A use B, B use C, C defines a variable X which A uses).  It is very difficult to refactor the code this way.  Are there any methods that will help me understand the structure of the code and what uses what?  For what it's worth, we already use strict.

Comment: Your last sentence made me smile. This is not fun if you have to deal with it daily, but it can be fun to rebuild it once you've unraveled it sufficiently.

Comment: Are those things `use` or `require` statements? Are the modules really modules (.pm files with `package`s in them), or do you have a lot of `require 'foo.pl'` kind of stuff, all in the `main` namespace?

Comment: There is also Devel::NYTProf, which can be helpful to understand who calls whom.

Comment: @eric If you found an answer provided here helpful, please upvote and/or mark as accepted, so that other users with a similar question can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but there is no Perl module or other generally available script that can do what your looking for. I had a similar problem once and had to write my own scripts (possibly using NYTProf eg) to parse each module and then analys the collected data externally.

Other than that you're left with commenting out all "use" statements then bring them back in one at a time, only after having done this process with any modules you bring in. A touch job, but you'll learn a lot about your code.

When you start to make changes expect unexpected failures because when you have circular use statements like this, the compilation depends on the order that code is introduced - meaning compilation errors in totally unrelated modules.

Good luck.